# No Route Matches [GET] "demo/hello"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Currently running through a ruby on rails guide and I seem to have hit a slight snag. I duplicated a view in one of my view folders:

hello.html.erb
and
index.html.erb

When trying to access it via browser (localhost:3000/demo/"...")
Only the original demo/index works but demo/hello has "No Route Matches"

Comment: Could you please paste your config/routes.rb??

Comment: The rails guides are excellent and answers this question http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thanks for the concern Zapico the problem has been solved.

Alexander thanks for the link I'm sure it will come in handy really soon.

Comment: Mark the answer as correct to close it ;)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add

```
 get "demo/hello" => "your-controller#your-action"
```

to your routes.rb

For example:

app/controllers/demos_controller.rb:

```
class DemosController < ApplicationController

  def hello
  end

end
```

app/views/demos/hello.html.erb:

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

config/routes.rb:

```
get "demo/hello" => "demos#hello"
```

**UPDATE:**
From the comments: check out the rails guide for more details: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thanks for the very clear solution. I figured it might be something like that. I'm at the beginning of the tutorial and it had me working off of rails "defaults" which I figured changed since the creation of the video series.

Comment: As a side note. If I am defining a new action and it renders text as opposed to a created view, will I need to create another route? I tried defining

def other_hello
   render(:text => 'Hello again')
end
But I got the same error as before "No Route Matches"

Comment: @GenoDiaz I'd recommend you to read this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: you always have to define routes for your actions.. check out the rails guide, it´s really helpful.

Answer (score -1):

get 'your url path', to: 'yourcontroller#youraction'
eg.

```
get '/demos/hello', to: 'demos#hello'
```